# Create a new item and delete item on button press polymer designer

Tags: browser, polymer, polymer-designer-tool

I'm having trouble. I, being the novice polymer user I am, am trying to make

```
<core-icon-button icon="add" id="core_icon_button7" theme="core-light-theme"></core-icon-button>
```

to create a new one of these...

```
<core-toolbar id="core_toolbar4">
          <core-icon-button icon="close" id="core_icon_button6"></core-icon-button>
          <div id="div1" flex>{{ inputValue }}</div>
        </core-toolbar>
```

while having the `close` button remove it. I would also like to know how I can make the `toolbars` have a button like function that switches pages while the `add` button creates a new page while `close` removes a selected page.

Comment: can you reformulate your question please,

Comment: I want the add button to make a new toolbar and page while the close button removes the toolbar and page. I would also like the toolbars to act as buttons that switch between pages. Basically I want to turn toolbars into tabs.

Comment: core-toolbar ?? this is the core-toolbar from polymer 0.5?
I dont understand your question but I think that you have to use polymer 1.+

Comment: @SarahTsaki What have you tried?

Comment: I'm using the polymer designer, which I know is outdated but I don't have a mac to get polymer 1.x and I haven't tried much but I attempted to mess with very simple coding like, `on-click` and other simple codes. I just want to make the `core-toolbar` to function like `paper-tabs`